# Unable to dock windows side to side in Windows7?

Tags: windows-7

I am unable to use the docking feature on windows 7 to view two separate windows side by side.Tried updating but no updates are required and cant find much at all on this issue.

Comment: windows is a program, no?

Comment: so you'll be asking how to use a knife & fork on a cooking site?

Comment: Exactly :) and spoon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Control panel >> Ease of access centre >> Make the mouse easier to use >> Uncheck windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the sceen